# udisk2 fail to mount

Tags: mount

On my Raspberry OS bullseye Lite system, when i try to mount a partition with udisks2 i get this error:

```
$ udisksctl  mount --block-device /dev/sda1 --no-user-interaction 
Error mounting /dev/sda1: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Error.NotAuthorizedCanObtain: Not authorized to perform operation
```

Is there any way to know which operation is not allowed? The `mount` is performed by udisksd running as root, so I think it's not the problem with  `mount`

What I would like to have happen is for the partition to be mounted in `/media/<user>/<id>` and to be mounted with uid and gid matching my user.